# Adding Children to StackPanel in Parent Window from UserControl in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a MainWindow and inside this MainWindow I have a UserControl loaded. The MainWindow has a StackPanel included. Now I want to add a button to that StackPanel from the UserControl.

If I directly Add it, it works (from MainWindow) - but not from the UserControl.

Example:

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var myTestRadioButton = new RadioButton
        {
            Name = "TestRadioButton",
            Height = 31.5,
            Width = 140,
        };

        MyStackPanel.Children.Add(myTestRadioButton);
    }
```

works

UserControl1.xaml.cs

```
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var parentWindow = new MainWindow();

        var myTestRadioButton = new RadioButton
        {
            Name = "TestRadioButton",
            Height = 31.5,
            Width = 140,
        };

        parentWindow.MyStackPanel.Children.Add(myTestRadioButton);
     }
```

doesn't work.

i tried with creating a static instance of the parent window as well...

funny thing is -> i get no error message or something like that.. it just doesnt work (e.g. the button doesnt show up...)

please help :) :) :)

Comment: **Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for.**

Comment: The best way would be to create an event for your usercontrol subscribe to it in your parent form and do your work there.

Comment: how would i solve that in XAML then?

Comment: the thing is - i want to realize a behavior like a tab control (but with buttons) with created *buttons* (like the tabs in a browser) - but the buttons are in the mainWindow, their content is in a UserControl - but i still want to switch like tabs ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doing this `var parentWindow = new MainWindow();` you are creating a `new window`  in your user control  not a reference to your current MainWindow

```
public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var parentWindow = new MainWindow();

            var myTestRadioButton = new RadioButton
            {
                Name = "TestRadioButton",
                Height = 31.5,
                Width = 140,
            };
         //just add something like this  
        public  void AddChildControl(Window MyWindow)
       {
              MyWindow.MyStackPanel.Children.Add(myTestRadioButton);
       }

     }
```

Change the MainWindow from user control

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var myTestRadioButton = new RadioButton
        {
            Name = "TestRadioButton",
            Height = 31.5,
            Width = 140,
        };

            var usercontrol1= new    UserControl1() ; 
             usercontrol.AddChildControl(this);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you make a new instance of the window. (sse answer of K B) this can't work anyway

if you really (for whatever) need dynamicaly GUI you should use another approach:

you may wanna have a stackpanel inside of your usercontrol

```
<Stackpanel x:Name="myStack"/>
```

codebehind:

```
Usercontrol()
{
myStack.Children.Add(new WhateverControl());
}
```